# Create defect template in Quality Center

Tags: quality-center

We are using Quality Center 10.00 Enterprise edition and I should have admin rights to my current project.

I would like to create a template for new defects, but can't find **where** to write the template script

I have found [this person](http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/Quality-Center-Support-and-News/Define-template-for-defect/td-p/4753307), that had the same problem, but the answers doesn't state where to write the script.

Comment: The link you've given isn't working @Pierre Can you summarise the page you linked to for us?

Comment: Updated the link, thank you for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Noticed that I have to be SITE admin to be able to customize the defect field in QC (and I am only project admin).

Once site admin, there will be a Workflow option under the project customization. And in workflow all the scripts are written.